# Are maggots still used in traditional medicine to eat away the dead-skin (necrosis) when a patient has gangrene and needs an amputation?

Tags: traditional-medicine, necrosis-dead-skin, amputation

Are maggots still used in traditional medicine to eat away the dead-skin (necrosis) when a patient has gangrene and needs an amputation? Is it effective? Where do they keep the maggots? Or do they order them in?

If not, what do they use instead to clear off all the dead skin?

(I'm assuming that they don't use maggots anymore, but am curious how it worked in the past, and what they do now)?